# Is returning with error code slower than out parameter?

Tags: c#, performance, go, tuples, out

*This issue touches Go and C# so the comparison would deal with **current** implementations -- I am rather looking for theoretical evidence, something like quick sort in worst case performance is...*

In many places dedicated to Go I saw a function that returns a tuple, with last element being an error code. In C# it is rather `TryXXX` pattern with last `out` parameter.

Now I wonder which one is better performer (once again, from theoretical standpoint -- meaning if you could implement it at best, what would be the outcome).

Maybe naive thinking, but with tuple approach I see memory allocation problem, you have to do it each time the function is called, no matter what. With `out` parameter you allocate memory outside the function, so then even if you call a function millions times, the cost is zero (well, except for copying some data).

`out` then should be a better performer, correct? Or is there some way to implement tuple passing to match `out`? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: It's much better for Go: Go could place the return values into registers so no memory allocation is done at all. (I think it doesn't do that right now). Also, if you care about performance, use C instead of Go.

Comment: @FUZxxl, if I am not mistaken it could be done only in corner cases, when the rest of the tuple is small, correct? But in the rest if would allocate memory.

Comment: Have a read about calling conventions. Go might pass the first couple of return parameter in registers and the rest on the stack.

Comment: Nothing stops you from using "out" parameters in Go if your profiling shows that THIS is the bottleneck. E.g. when return value is a slice, it's common to fill the given slice instead of creating a new one on each call. In case of int value - it doesn't matter, you will never see the difference in real world use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way multiple return values are implemented by the current Go suite (gc) the return values are passed the same way parameters are, which are on stack. There is no memory allocation at that point (Assuming the stack size was sufficient, which is another matter). Considering the out parameter in C# would need to be allocated, I'd say the Go approach would be faster but not because of the approach in itself but by the fact that non-primitive data types are heap allocated in C# whereas in Go the programmer can choose to keep it on stack.

If we consider simply the parameter passing versus the multiple return value, the performance impact would be non-existant since both represent a push/pop on the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanatory answer!